# MySQL update apenas um campo de uma linha

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Em MysSQL tenho uma tabela assim:

[image: ID]

Recebo em um PHP via POST o **id** da tabela e qual **foto** devo limpar do banco de dados:

```
id= 1
foto = aaa.jpg
```

Com UPDATE preciso deixar a tabela assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, apenas limpar o campo da tabela com id **1**, onde o valor da foto for igual a **aaa.jpg**. Como fazer? A dificuldade está em saber se a foto aaa.jpg está na coluna **FOTO1**, **FOTO2** ou **FOTO3**

Acredito que seja com IF dentro do SET, algo assim que imagino ser a forma:

```
UPDATE tabela SET foto1 = '' IF(foto1='aaa.jpg'), foto2 = '' IF(foto2='aaa.jpg'), foto3 = '' IF(foto3='aaa.jpg')
WHERE id = '1'
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940759/find-column-that-contains-a-given-value-in-mysql)  do SOEN, pode te ajudar

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XPsre3Yv

Comment: Complicado entender o que voce precisa... mas vamos tentar!

Comment: @ValdeirPsr perfeito! Era isso.

Comment: Não seria uma das soluções do seu problema criar uma tabela n-n, atributo multi-valorado? Assim você poderia buscar na tabela pelo nome da foto... Ou até mesmo nomear suas colunas de acordo com o uso. Obs: Agora entendi o que quis perguntar kkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
UPDATE 
   fotos
SET 
   FOTO1 = IF(FOTO1='aaa.jpg', NULL, FOTO1),
   FOTO2 = IF(FOTO2='aaa.jpg', NULL, FOTO2),
   FOTO3 = IF(FOTO3='aaa.jpg', NULL, FOTO3),
WHERE 
   'aaa.jpg' IN (FOTO1 , FOTO2, FOTO3) AND ID = 1
```

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46093439/7437072

---

Ou como foi sugerido nos comentário pelo [Valdeir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/99718/valdeir-psr):

```
UPDATE
  `fotos`
SET
  `foto1` = REPLACE(`foto1`, 'aaa.jpg', ''),
  `foto2` = REPLACE(`foto2`, 'aaa.jpg', ''),
  `foto3` = REPLACE(`foto3`, 'aaa.jpg', '')
WHERE
  id = 1
```